# preventing error messages on website

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using a third party API, which uses

```
trigger_error function
```

on errors.

which in turn will be displayed on the website. What is a better way to prevent showing such errors on website?

Comment: Turn off error reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using cakephp change the debug to 0  in Config/core.php

```
/**
 * CakePHP Debug Level:
 *
 * Production Mode:
 *  0: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown. Flash messages redirect.
 *
 * Development Mode:
 *  1: Errors and warnings shown, model caches refreshed, flash messages halted.
 *  2: As in 1, but also with full debug messages and SQL output.
 *
 * In production mode, flash messages redirect after a time interval.
 * In development mode, you need to click the flash message to continue.
 */
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this on top of your PHP file

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dainis Abols said, you could simply turn off Error Reporting using the [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function call at the head of each document, or you could place it in an include file that is used commonly across all documents. The most effective meathod is changing it in your php.ini file however, where you would change [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to prevent all errors means need not show any errors in your script or 3rd part API you can use

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

If you need to prevent some errors in particular line of code use @ infront of that line it will suppress errors

See here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php